# How do I ensure all methods in a module have the same signature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass

All of the functions in a class within a module are required to have the following signature:

```
def func(i, x, y):
  return ('done', (1,2) )
```

All functions are static.
Each function in my class should have three arguments.
The return should be a tuple.

Is that possible to do? Can metaclass be used there?

Comment: What is the point?  Without static type enforcement, all three arguments to the functions could be literally any type -- builtin types, custom types, collections, classes, anything.  Just curious what the design idea is behind this.

Comment: I am building a library where callers can integrate it with their application. They will pass a class to its constructor and my library will execute the function. Hence it's important for each function that it execute to have a specific signature and return type

Comment: And I want to use a metaclass so that at module import time, it can tell the user whether the class meets the standard. I can live with not checking the return type. Anyways, it must be possible

Comment: Rather than a metaclass, require your users to subclass something with an `__init_subclass__` method that does the checks (using `inspect`, as suggested Samwise's answer.)

Comment: Why not use metaclass and do it in__new__?

Comment: You could use a metaclass an do it in `__new__` - but that would giver your users more constraints thantthey need: if thy want a metaclass in their own plugable classes, that metaclass wold have to be combined with yours, guard metaclass. With `__init_subclass__` in a base class there is less bueaucracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the key missing in the question, you completed as a comment - you want the check at import time.

Just create a base class with  a proper `__init_subclass__` do the checking.

```py
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kw)
        for name, obj in cls.__dict__.items():
            if callable(obj) or isinstance(obj, classmethod):
                raise TypeError(f"All methods in class {cls.__name__} should be declared static")
            if isinstance(obj, staticmethod) and len(inspect.signature(obj.__get__(None, cls)).parameters) != 3:
                raise TypeError(f"All functions inside class {cls.__name__} must accept exactly 3 parameters")
            # class attributes that are not methods are ignored
```

You could use a metaclass instead if you'd like to auto-apply the `staticmethod` decorator to all declared functions inside the class:

```py
class CheckPlugin(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        for attr_name, obj in namespace.items():
            if callable(obj):
                obj = staticmethod(obj)
                namespace[attr_name] = obj
            if isinstance(obj, classmethod):
                raise TypeError(f"All methods in class {name} should be written as static methods")
            if isinstance(obj, staticmethod) and len(inspect.signature(obj.__get__(None, cls)).parameters) != 3:
                raise TypeError(f"All functions inside class {name} must accept exactly 3 parameters")
            # class attributes that are not methods are ignored
        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
```

(On  a second thought, nothing would prevent you from changing the methods to staticmethods on the `__init_subclass__` just as well -  the metaclass is really not needed):

```py
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kw)
        for name, obj in list(cls.__dict__.items()):  # the list() call iterates on a static copy of the class's proxy dict, as it will be modified in interation
            if callable(obj):
                obj = staticmethod(obj)
                setattr(cls, name, obj)
                
            if isinstance(obj, classmethod):
                raise TypeError(f"All methods in class {cls.__name__} should be declared static")
            if isinstance(obj, staticmethod) and len(inspect.signature(obj.__get__(None, cls)).parameters) != 3:
                raise TypeError(f"All functions inside class {cls.__name__} must accept exactly 3 parameters")
            # class attributes that are not methods are ignored
```

And, finally, as stated in the question comments, there is no way to check the return-value type of each function just with the functions - they could be annotated, and the code above could inspect the annotation, though (and raise an error if the return value is not annotated properly). To validate that the annotation is not "lying", the only way to go is to make proper use of Mypy and static type checking prior to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of type annotations, static type checking, and unit tests to enforce this.

Use a unit test with `inspect` to iterate over all the methods in the class and verify that they're annotated with the correct signature:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Then use `mypy` to validate that the implementations of the methods match the annotations:

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/